# Не удаётся неявно преобразовать тип double в тип bool. C#

Tags: c#, double, bool

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Решите уравнение: 2x + 2,5 = 6"); 
 double result1 = Convert.ToDouble( Console.ReadLine() ); //1,75

Console.WriteLine("Решите уравнение: 4(x - 1) = 6x + 5"); 
 double result2 = Convert.ToDouble( Console.ReadLine() ); //-4,5

 if ( result1 == 1,75  && result2 == -4,5  ) {
     Console.WriteLine("Оба уравнения решены верно!");
 }

Console.ReadKey();
```

Совсем недавно начал изучать C#, до этого был лишь немного знаком с Python 3.
В этой задаче нужно было проверить решения любых математических примеров, но меня застопорила ошибка преобразования данных.

Comment: `if (result1 == 1.75 && result2 == -4.75)` десятичные дроби в C# коде через точку пишутся.

Comment: Я думал, что нужно то же самое, что и в консоли, потому что консоль у меня отказывается обрабатывать точки.

Comment: Это зависит от локализации, в русской локализации числа выводятся и вводятся через запятую, в английской или инвариантной - через точку. А в коде всегда через точку. Локаль ввода-вывода можно настроить как угодно, есть такой класс `CultureInfo`, он отвечает за локали. Но это уже другая длинная история.

Comment: А можно добавлять несколько параметров else? Если можно, то как это сделать?

Comment: `if () {} else if () {} else if() {} else`. `switch() { case }` еще есть.

Comment: Вот у меня условия точку с запятой требуют почему-то. И подчёркивает красной линией кавычку "{". А куда этот знак препинания в коде поставить, я в душе не чаю. И просит именно после параметра else.

Comment: Всем спасибо, проблемы решил!! Люблю вас.